# express router to get all the possible parameters

Tags: regex, node.js, express

suppose there is url like

```
http://xyz.abc/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k
http://xyz.abc/a/b/c/d/e/f/
```

how to take any number of parameter by express

trying to use it with

```
router.use("/:param1/:param2/:param3",express.static('./public/index.html'));
router.use("/:param1/:param2/:param3/:param4/:param5",express.static('./public/index.html'));
```

possible regular expression tried but failed

```
router.use('\/:(\w+)', express.static('./public/index.html'))
```

Comment: Just use some middleware that sees all requests and then split the path yourself to get all the segments.

Comment: tried router.use('*', express.static('./public/index.html')); it works but is it good solution?

Comment: What are you really trying to do with that?  Are you just trying to serve the same file no matter what the path is?  If so, please edit your question to say that.

Comment: @jfriend00 what is wrong with the question? I have shared examples I am trying too

Comment: You have shown some solutions, but have not actually described the real problem you're trying to solve and that means we can't offer you the best solution.  All we can do is point out problems in your proposed solution.  If you really just trying to serve the same index.html no matter what the path is, then you're going about it the wrong way, but we can't advise you on that without knowing what the actual problem is you're trying to solve.

Comment: This is often known as the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you send us down a particular solution path without describing the actual root problem therefore we cannot offer you the best solution (outside of your already narrowed solution path).  We can serve you better if you back up a few steps and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve - pretend you know nothing about possible solutions.

Comment: I want to take any no of parameters Express, thought could use regex, you said to use middleware, I showed how I used... does it matter to send it to function or some html? thanks for negation on question though, cant blame all the foolish in the internet :D

Comment: Well, you were given an answer that takes any number of parameters and outputs the same file and now you somehow say that isn't what you want.  We simply don't know what you want!  Thus your question is apparently unclear.  I already told you that if you want to actually process all the path parameters in your own code, then just make a route for anything and get the path and call .split("/") on it an you will have all the path segments.  Now, you've been given several answers, but don't seem happy with any of them.  So, we apparently don't know what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: When multiple people are confused about what you want, it is on YOU to clarify your question so you can get the type of answer you actually want.  If you're only interested in answers that use express wildcards, then I will bow out of this question because that doesn't tell us why or what problem you're actually trying to solve so thus we can't help very well.  You have the downvote because your question is unclear and you are not clarifying it.  We've given you multiple solutions that will serve the same file for any path. Until you edit your question to clarify, nothing else we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a middleware so that every request directs to that middleware. Send the file in that middleware.

For example:-

```
var express = require('express);
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/abc.html'));
});
```

Comment: this works, but I want to get regex for multi-parameter :D I made it work with router.use('*', express.static('./public/index.html'))